# What do you call the person who runs parties, weddings, and organizes party games?

Tags: expressions, nouns, synonyms

It's similar to a DJ, but I don't mean night clubs or music only. What is the general word for a person who directs the crowd during a party, and announces things?

Toast master is one word.
Show runner?
Anchor man?
Party announcer?
MC - master of ceremony? But this is only for breakdance, rap battles etc.

I'd like to know other synonyms.

Comment: May be we can call him/her a 'social butterfly' -A social butterfly is a slang term for a person who is socially dynamic, networking, charismatic, and personally gregarious. (Wiki)

Comment: @MystiSinha, I think a social butterfly would "work the room" and be quite comfortable at a party but wouldn't necessarily be the one running the games, etc. - though they would probably do quite well at that, given their gregarious nature.

Comment: @Mysti Sinha: I don't think so. A *social butterfly* is usually someone who "promiscuously" spreads their [superficial] social contact across many people. Particularly, *in different social groups*, leading to the common implication that such a person isn't particularly *committed* to any specific social group, and would therefore be unlikely to actively *organise* group activities.

Comment: i've heard party planner for this, but party planners don't necessarily *attend* the party, i suppose

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Master of ceremonies (MC) is actually a good fit here.

It's true that MC is a term used in hip-hop, but that's simply borrowed from the more general term.

[MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/master+of+ceremonies?show=0&t=1417795965) notes that the term is from the 1600s... predates hip-hop quite a bit

Comment: I feel like 'emcee' has become to mean more of this while MC implies the rap connection (however it was originally intended).  My only source for this is my gut, though.

Answer (score 0):

You could use **event organizer**

At many commercial/party venues, this person is typically a staff member of the venue. At smaller/informal gatherings, the event organizer and the host may be one in the same person.